# Listview при выводе выводит только последнее значение

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

`введите сюда код`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все данные правильно берет из бд  но при отображение на списке выводит только последнее данные из бд
                public void getdata(){

```
         String 
       url="http://*******";
        JsonObjectRequest js= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
      url, null, 
     new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray mas= response.getJSONArray("users");
                 arr.clear();
            for(int i=0; i<mas.length(); i++){
                JSONObject row = mas.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("LOGGG", String.valueOf(map));
                map.put("from",row.getString("from_"));
                map.put("to",row.getString("to_"));
                map.put("price",row.getString("price"));
                map.put("comment",row.getString("comment"));
                map.put("id_order",row.getString("id_order"));
                map.put("price",row.getString("phone"));
                arr.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

         }
         });


        r.add(js);
        ЭТО КОД У МЕНЯ НА КНОПКУ ПРИКРЕПЛЕН
```

Comment: Добавьте код вместо скриншота

Comment: for(int i=0; i<mas.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject row = mas.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("LOGGG", String.valueOf(map));
                    map.put("from",row.getString("from_"));
                    map.put("to",row.getString("to_"));
                    map.put("price",row.getString("price"));
                    map.put("comment",row.getString("comment"));
                    map.put("id_order",row.getString("id_order"));
                    map.put("price",row.getString("phone"));
                    arr.add(map);
                }

Comment: @НурлыбайУзакбаев, не в комменты) В вопрос, через правку оного

Comment: @НурлыбайУзакбаев, кажется вы не добавляете, но перезаписыаете значение в цикле.

Comment: Как можно исправить, я просто новичок в этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас в классе есть переменная `map` в кою вы в цикле пишете данные. В итоге в каждой итерации вы перезатираете значения в этой переменной. Вывод - вам надо использовать не одну переменную, но новую в каждой итерации цикла. Как-то так:

```
for(int i=0; i<mas.length(); i++){
    JSONObject row = mas.getJSONObject(i);
    Map map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("from",row.getString("from_"));
    map.put("to",row.getString("to_"));
    map.put("price",row.getString("price"));
    map.put("comment",row.getString("comment"));
    map.put("id_order",row.getString("id_order"));
    map.put("price",row.getString("phone"));
    arr.add(map);
}
```

Comment: О сделал спасибо большое!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите создание переменной за пределы for

```
    Map map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<mas.length(); i++){
    JSONObject row = mas.getJSONObject(i);
    map.put("from",row.getString("from_"));
    map.put("to",row.getString("to_"));
    map.put("price",row.getString("price"));
    map.put("comment",row.getString("comment"));
    map.put("id_order",row.getString("id_order"));
    map.put("price",row.getString("phone"));
    arr.add(map);
    }
```

Comment: Это не решит проблему. Именно в том, что переменная за циклом и есть проблема